# How to send a dictionary with Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, dictionary, alamofire

I need to send a dictionary but first I need to place in into a variable. This is what I got:

```
 let params = [
                "origen": "iphone",
                "app":"myApp",
                "version":"a555efce-465f-4c8b-b2d5-432278afa7f7",
                "cuenta":"facebook",
                "usuario":"123456",
                "hash":"abc123",
                "zona_horaria":"1",
                "idioma":"es_ES",
                "operaciones": [
                    "id":"0",
                    "operacion":"registrarInfoUsuario",
                    "parametros":[

                        "perfil":[
                            "email":"pruebas2@adksa.com",
                            "firstname":"Pruebas2",
                            "lastname":"Probacioso"],
                        "intereses":"",
                        "deseos":"",
                        "vistos":"",
                        "amigos":""]

                                ],
            ]
```

I think I have a syntax error because I can't make the request. I'm using Alamofire. My request is:

```
request(.GET, self.url, parameters: params, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON{res in

                print(JSON(res.result.value!)) //debug
}
```

I'm pretty sure all it's about `let param = ...`.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Syntax error? What error? If you have one, XCode should says it. If not, it may be the request that is wrong, but it may help to give then the error that should be thrown by Alamofire for that request.